# Is there a way to extract rows from dataframes, that is in a list of dataframes

Tags: python, regex, pandas, list, dataframe

For this project I built a web crawler. The crawler goes to a league home page on baseball reference, and collects all of the team links found on that page, appending them to a list, and then scraping all the links in that list, collecting data on each player that played on that team for a given season. When it is done, it returns a list of a list of dataframes. In this example there are 22 teams, so it returns a list, that contains 22 lists of player dataframes. Totaling at about 640 total dataframes (players).

Here is an example of one of those player dataframes:
(nwl_21 is the list, and the first index gets the first of 22 teams, and the second index of 0 gets the first player on that team)

```
nwl_21[0][0]

1 to 7 of 7 entries
Filter

index   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19
0                           NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
1   19  -2.2    Grand Canyon    WAC NCAA    None    4.0 11.0    10.0    0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 4.0 0.0
2   20  -1.8    Grand Canyon    WAC NCAA    None    32.0    82.0    70.0    3.0 12.0    0.0 0.0 1.0 5.0 1.0 0.0 3.0 24.0    0.171
3   20  -0.5    Kokomo  NWDS    Smr None    35.0    145.0   118.0   18.0    20.0    1.0 1.0 0.0 11.0    0.0 0.0 22.0    27.0    0.17
4   None    College None    36  93  80  3.0 12.0    0.0 0.0 1.0 5.0 2.0 0.0 3.0 28.0    0.15    0.207   0.188   0.394
5   None    Other   None    35  145 118 18.0    20.0    1.0 1.0 0.0 11.0    0.0 0.0 22.0    27.0    0.17    0.317   0.195   0.512
6   None    None    None    71  238 198 21.0    32.0    1.0 1.0 1.0 16.0    2.0 0.0 25.0    55.0    0.162   0.276   0.192   0.468
```

Now my goal is to access the rows that contain 'NCAA' and 'NWDS' and store it somewhere.
The ultimate goal is to have a large sample of this data so I can build a multiple regression model, that can predict performance in the 'NWDS' League, based off of prior 'NCAA' statistics.

Any and all help is greatly appriciated.

Comment: df[(df == 'NCAA').any(axis=1)] with df=nwl_21[0][0]  ?

Comment: What? is that even python?

Answer (score 2):

If we call df the dataframe in the question and if we want to put in a dataframe df2, the rows of df whose values are equal to 'NCAA' or 'NWDS', we can use the following Pyhton line:

```
df2 = df[((df == 'NCAA')|(df == 'NWDS')).any(axis=1)]
```

**Update**: If we want to get the lines which contains 'NCAA' and 'NWDS':

```
df2 = df[(df == 'NCAA').any(axis=1)&(df == 'NWDS').any(axis=1)]
```

Comment: IIUC the request is to return rows that contain NCAA and NWDS, not one or the other.

Comment: @Matthew Borish, thanks for the comment. I updated the answer to show both.

Comment: Thank you so much, it makes sense however when  I run this I get an error that says:

Comment: AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'any'

Comment: Strange. It works fine on my side. The only thing I can think of to get the error you have is if df is a list and not a dataframe because then the comparison would give only one element (boolean) and clearly it doesn't have an any attribute. Did you use the line above with df = nwl_21[0][0] ? with df = nwl_21[0] I get the same error as you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression to find the rows that contain NCAA and NWDS. Here we have a `find_strs()` function that we can use on each row in the df with .apply() and `axis=1`. In this special case, the entire row is getting converted to a list, and then a string as our `find_strs()` argument.

```
import pandas as pd
import re

df = pd.DataFrame({
 1: {0: '20', 1: '20', 2: 'None', 3: 'None', 4: 'None'},
 2: {0: '-1.8', 1: '-0.5', 2: 'College', 3: 'NCAA', 4: 'None'},
 3: {0: 'Grand', 1: 'Kokomo', 2: 'None', 3: 'NWDS', 4: 'None'},
 4: {0: 'NWDS', 1: 'NWDS', 2: '36', 3: '35', 4: '71'},
 5: {0: 'WAC', 1: 'Smr', 2: '93', 3: '145', 4: '238'},
 6: {0: 'NCAA', 1: 'None', 2: '80', 3: '118', 4: '198'},
 7: {0: 'None', 1: '35.0', 2: '3.0', 3: '18.0', 4: '21.0'}})


def find_strs(row_string):
    
    pattern = re.compile(r'^(?=.*NWDS)(?=.*NCAA).+$')
    
    if pattern.match(row_string):
        return True 
    
    else:
        return False
    
df['str_match'] = df.apply(lambda row : find_strs(str(row.tolist())), axis=1)
```

Output df:

```
        1       2       3       4       5   6       7     str_match
0       20      -1.8    Grand   NWDS    WAC NCAA    None    True
1       20      -0.5    Kokomo  NWDS    Smr None    35.0    False
2       None    College None    36      93  80      3.0     False
3       None    NCAA    NWDS    35      145 118     18.0    True
4       None    None    None    71      238 198     21.0    False
```

Next we can take a slice of the matching rows with this.

```
df = df.loc[df['str_match'] == True]
```

Output df:

```
    1      2    3       4       5   6       7       str_match
0   20    -1.8  Grand   NWDS    WAC NCAA    None    True
3   None  NCAA  NWDS    35      145 118     18.0    True
```

So basically what I would do is run this on each of your dfs with a for loop and append the df with the match rows to a list. Then you can use `pd.concat()` with your new list of df slices. This part should be pretty simple, but post a comment if you need a hand and I will add to this answer.

Edit:

Here's the whole sequence.

```
df_a = pd.DataFrame({
 1: {0: '20', 1: '20', 2: 'None', 3: 'None', 4: 'None'},
 2: {0: '-1.8', 1: '-0.5', 2: 'College', 3: 'NCAA', 4: 'None'},
 3: {0: 'Grand', 1: 'Kokomo', 2: 'None', 3: 'NWDS', 4: 'None'},
 4: {0: 'NWDS', 1: 'NWDS', 2: '36', 3: '35', 4: '71'},
 5: {0: 'WAC', 1: 'Smr', 2: '93', 3: '145', 4: '238'},
 6: {0: 'NCAA', 1: 'None', 2: '80', 3: '118', 4: '198'},
 7: {0: 'None', 1: '35.0', 2: '3.0', 3: '18.0', 4: '21.0'}})


df_b = pd.DataFrame({
 1: {0: '20', 1: '20', 2: 'None', 3: 'None', 4: 'None'},
 2: {0: '-1.8', 1: '-0.5', 2: 'College', 3: 'None', 4: 'None'},
 3: {0: 'Grand', 1: 'Kokomo', 2: 'None', 3: 'NWDS', 4: 'None'},
 4: {0: 'NWDS', 1: 'NWDS', 2: '36', 3: '35', 4: '71'},
 5: {0: 'WAC', 1: 'Smr', 2: '93', 3: '145', 4: '238'},
 6: {0: 'NCAA', 1: 'None', 2: '80', 3: '118', 4: '198'},
 7: {0: 'None', 1: '35.0', 2: 'NCAA', 3: '18.0', 4: 'NWDS'}})

df_list_pre = [df_a, df_b]

df_list_post = []

for df in df_list_pre:

    df['str_match'] = df.apply(lambda row : find_strs(str(row.tolist())), axis=1)
    
    df = df.loc[df['str_match'] == True]
    
    df_list_post.append(df)
    

concat_df = pd.concat(df_list_post)
```

Output:

```
    1      2    3       4     5     6       7       str_match
0   20    -1.8  Grand   NWDS  WAC   NCAA    None    True
3   None  NCAA  NWDS    35    145   118     18.0    True
0   20    -1.8  Grand   NWDS  WAC   NCAA    None    True
```

Comment: So while I do not totally understand it since I have not used regex before, it seems to be working. I ran it on each of my dfs with a nested for loop, but when I try and append it to a list the list just contains 8 total false values and I am not exactly sure how I messed up.

Comment: See my edit. You shouldn't need any nesting in the for loop.

Comment: Okay it makes a lot of sense, and I get no errors. But my concat_df is just empty.

Comment: If you're able to get the regex find_strs() to work on individual dfs, than the loop part shouldn't have problems. If you can post some more slices of example dfs it would help. Using .to_dict() on your dfs and then copying and pasting into example works well.

Comment: Posting your for loop code will help too.

Comment: Yes I apologize I should have included the code. I will edit it right now